# VueJS dynamically mounting or attaching components based on responsiveness

Tags: css, responsive-design, vue.js, responsive, responsiveness

I have a question about VueJS and responsiveness. Let's assume I have the following template with a sidebar and the home component:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="row" style="margin-right:0px;">
            <div class="sidebar col-md-2" style="position:fixed">
                <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                <app-home></app-home>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar.vue';
    import Home from './components/Home.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            appSidebar: Sidebar,
            appHome: Home
        }
    }
</script>
```

Next thing I want to do is adding a third component, e.g. 'quickbar'. If the size is above 1000px, I want the 'quickbar' component to be added to sidebar col-md-2 div element, above the app-sidebar. If it's below 1000px I want the 'quickbar' component to be added to the col-md-10, below the app-home. What is the best approach for this? Adding the same component twice and using an @media css with display:none? How will this work?

Comment: I would personally solve that by adding the component twice and use a v-if clause with a variable based on the window.size property. Don't know whether that's the best way.

Comment: @Imre_G Adding the component twice might be OK, but certainly do not use JavaScript to get the window size. That is what media queries are for.